# How can I include many images on my webpage while making fewer HTTP requests

Tags: html, http

I have to make a website a sort of for ex. WWW.outgrow.me
when the main page gets loaded for every image it goes to server is there any idea to load the number of images at once from the server and display them on main page so that to get rid off multiple http requests to server from client side

regards

Comment: [Image sprites (CSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can, use [image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). These are images combined into one file, which reduces the number of HTTP requests, and thus should speed up your site.
2. Also look at implementing the [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) HTTP header, this should reduce the time it takes to load multiple resources.
3. Especially important if you're using PHP or some other language to render static content, use the `Expires` and `Cache-control` headers properly, to make sure that users don't load the content every time they visit a new page.

Comment: Spites are background images. Don't use them for content images.

Comment: Sprites are appropriate for logos and such, I wasn't suggesting combine all your JPG photos into a single file.